# Drawing a curve which start in (-2,-4) goes in (0,0) and then in (4,4)

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hi I write this code but I don't understand why its not curve..

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure} [htb]
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[-latex] (-2,0) -- (6,0) node[right] {$Return\%$};
 \draw[-latex] (0,-4) -- (0,6) node[above] {$Utility$};
\draw (-2,-4) .. controls (0,0) and (0,0)..(5,5); 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I need to do this thanks[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

where are the errors??

Comment: I'd use three points and to the control points as relative polar coordinates, `++(30:1)`, then the control points are vectors at the end of the curve segments and by controlling the length and direction you control the curve. Just make sure that the two control points in and out of zero, are on the same line, but opposite directions.

Comment: You need to put the line `\usepackage{tikz}` in your preamble, and change the capital H to a small h in `\begin{figure}[H]`. That's what is preventing your current code from compiling!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from using control points (which specify the direction of the curve but not the coordinates of the curve itself, as demonstrated by the useful answer of A. Ellet) you can also draw a coordinate plot with smoothing. Add more coordinates to make it smoother. Alternatively, with `pgfplots` you can draw a mathematical function that looks like the curve you want, which will be smooth without adding coordinates or control points, however it may be difficult to find the right function.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1.0,lightgray,thin] (-2,-4) grid (7,4);
\draw[-latex] (-2,0) -- (7,0) node[right] {$Return\%$};
\draw[-latex] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node[above] {$Utility$};
\draw[blue] plot [smooth] coordinates { (-2,-4) (0,0) (3,2.5) (7,4) };
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-2,xmax=6,ymin=-4,ymax=4,axis lines=middle,xlabel={return},ylabel={utility}]
\addplot[samples=200,domain=-2:6] {(-((x-5.5)*(x-5.5))+30)/8};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

There's certainly more powerful tools available.  Nevertheless, here's a simple approach that renders:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\def\aeAngleAB{80}
\def\aeAngleCD{55}
\def\aeANgleEF{5}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%%
                    %% control point/.style={inner sep=2pt,circle,draw=red},
                    control point/.style={inner sep=2pt,circle},
                    primary point/.style={inner sep=2pt,circle,draw=blue},
                   ]

 \draw[-latex] (-2,0) -- (6,0) node[right] {$Return\%$};
 \draw[-latex] (0,-4) -- (0,6) node[above] {$Utility$};

\node[primary point] (P1) at (-2,-4) {};
\node[primary point] (P2) at (0,0) {};
\node[primary point] (P3) at (7,4) {};

\node[control point]  (C1) at ($(P1)+(\aeAngleAB:10pt)$)      {};
\node[control point]  (C2) at ($(P2)+(180+\aeAngleCD:40pt)$) {};
\node[control point]  (C3) at ($(P2)+(\aeAngleCD:110pt)$)    {};
\node[control point]  (C4) at ($(P3)+(180+\aeANgleEF:60pt)$) {};

%% \path[dashed,magenta,draw] (P1) -- (C1) -- (C2) -- (P2) -- (C3) -- (C4) -- (P3);
\path[dashed,magenta] (P1) -- (C1) -- (C2) -- (P2) -- (C3) -- (C4) -- (P3);

\draw[blue] (P1) .. controls (C1) and (C2) .. (P2);
\draw[blue] (P2) .. controls (C3) and (C4) .. (P3);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Add `draw=red` to the key `control point` and add `draw` to the `\path[dashed,magenta]` to see the interaction between control points and the graph

[image]

Comment: @Tommaso Dellolmo This is a great suggestion for how to get the result you want, but I just want to stress that your problems were caused by not loading the `tikz` package and wrong syntax for the `figure` environment.

Comment: I forgot to copy it ahaha sorry